# WPF - Textbox binding decimal value

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox, string-formatting

I'm writing a WPF program in c# and I'm trying to figure a way to bind two textboxes with decimal values. I have two different textboxes bind with two different properties.

I would like that when the user change the "Cost" the "Price" will be automatically filled, and when he will change the "Price" the cost will be automatically filled too. This produce like a **loop**, that I don't want.
And also I noticed that a textbox bind with a decimal value does not allow to add the comma and dot chars `'.'` and `','` .

How can i fix these two issues?

These are the XAML of textboxes:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Cost" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"   Text="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Price" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding Price ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And these are the two properties:

```
private decimal _cost;
public decimal Cost
{
    get { return _cost; }
    set
    {
        if (_cost != value)
        {
            _cost = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Cost");

            if (Cost > 0)
            {
                Price = Math.Round(_cost * ((decimal)1.50), 2);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Price");
            }

        }
    }
}

private decimal _price;
public decimal Price
{
    get { return _price; }
    set
    {
        if (_price != value)
        {
            _price = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Price");

            if (Price > 0)
            {
                Cost = Math.Round(Price / (decimal)(1.55), 2);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Cost");
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**
Searching on the net I've found the solution [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1252/entering-decimal-value-in-wpf-textbox-which-is-binding-by-do.aspx) is just necessary to add `StringFormat=0{0.0}`. Hope it will help someone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use backfields to set the values. see the flowing

```
private decimal _cost;
public decimal Cost
{
    get { return _cost; }
    set
    {
        if (_cost != value)
        {
            _cost = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Cost");

            if (_cost > 0)
            {
                _price = Math.Round(_cost * ((decimal)1.50), 2);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Price");
            }

        }
    }
}

private decimal _price;
public decimal Price
{
    get { return _price; }
    set
    {
        if (_price != value)
        {
            _price = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Price");

            if (_price > 0)
            {
                _cost = Math.Round(_price / (decimal)(1.55), 2);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Cost");
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped me to fix the loop, but in the textbox i still can't insert the comma  ' , ' and the dot ' . ', seems like the textbox doesn't me allow to insert them

Comment: Use a converter for converting the value back and forward.